# WordPress PHP Warning: simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, error-log

I'm facing the following error in my WordPress Site

```
[03-Sep-2017 10:12:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file():  in /home/syriacar/public_html/syria-cart.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/modules/wpml/wpml-config.php on line 53
```

and here is the file error content

```
    foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
        if ( file_exists( $file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . dirname( $plugin ) . '/wpml-config.xml' ) && false !== $xml = simplexml_load_file( $file ) ) {
            $this->xmls[ dirname( $plugin ) ] = $xml;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `wpml-config.xml` file?

Comment: here it is:  <wpml-config>
 <custom-types>
  <custom-type translate="1">project</custom-type>
 </custom-types>
 <admin-texts>
  <key name="mh_mharty">
   <key name="mharty_date_format" />
   <key name="mharty_seo_home_titletext" />
   <key name="mharty_seo_home_descriptiontext" />
   <key name="mharty_seo_home_keywordstext" />
  </key>
 </admin-texts>
</wpml-config>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to malformed *wpml-config.xml* file.

For example, on [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-error-25/) support WordPress forum page, you can find a similar issue and the cause was missing `</key>` closing tag before `</admin-texts>`.

**UPDATE:**

In your comments, you also mention yith-woocommerce-af‌​filiates warning, so another possibility is that the YITH WooCommerce Affiliates plugin doesn't have the wpml-config.xml or is empty.

The [polylang documentation](https://polylang.pro/doc/the-wpml-config-xml-file/) about wpml-config.xml mentions the following:

> Developpers must place the wpml-config.xml file in the root directory
>   of the plugin or theme.

Comment: I looked into it, but everything looks fine

Comment: Yes, I have seen your xml file, seems fine. Is that Warning "[03-Sep-2017 10:12:36 UTC] PHP Warning:" only warning about simplexml_load_file() or are there others too before or after that warning?

Comment: actually there are three here they are:  `[03-Sep-2017 20:19:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): /home/syriacar/public_html/syria-cart.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-affiliates/wpml-config.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty in /home/syriacar/public_html/syria-cart.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/modules/wpml/wpml-config.php on line 53
[03-Sep-2017 20:19:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file():  in /home/syriacar/public_html/syria-cart.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/modules/wpml/wpml-config.php on line 53

`

Comment: `[03-Sep-2017 20:19:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /home/syriacar/public_html/syria-cart.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/modules/wpml/wpml-config.php on line 53`